# C# script camera relative movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am brand new to coding and have no idea how to code in camera relative movement for an FPS in unity no youtube tutorials helped would anybody be able to give me a hand.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As @AndrewCorrigan mentioned, please feel free to share the piece of work that you had tried so far, have a look at this https://godottutorials.pro/fps-player-camera-tutorial/ may be something you are looking for..

Comment: Don’t get hung up on the word camera. As there is. Lot about fps under unity out there

Comment: I literally didn't have any code at all until today I can post it when I get home